# What component do I need to get this Calendar?

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I'm trying to get the Calendar from [here](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/calendar.html) running.

I've no experience working with GlassFish or the JavaServer Faces components, and so I'm lost when I read the tutorial saying that the Calendar should appear on my Palette? Is it my Netbeans Palette or is elsewhere? I downloaded GlassFish and ran the .jar but I don't see any changes on my Netbeans palette.

Shouldn't the Woodstock component, downloaded separately, be enough at least to get the Calendar appearing on the palette? Plus, where should I place that module to get it running? It's a nbm file.

Edit: The Woodstock component is now installed. How do I get it on my palette from Palette Manager?

Comment: I don't know about that tutorial but I can tell you the it should be definitely the Netbeans Palette for GlashFish don't have anything like a palette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to download any additional components. Calendar component is already included with the default woodstock components. You can find it in the palette while editing your web page in NetBeans. If the palette is closed, you can find it in "Window > Palette" menu or by pressing Ctrl+Shift+8. Calendar component is in the "Woodstock Basic" section. Just drag it from there on to your page.

If you want to add other components packed in .nbm module, here are the instructions for NetBeans 6.5:

- just go to the Plugins dialog in "Tools > Plugins" menu
- go to the "Downloaded" tab
- click "Add Plugins..." button and locate your downloaded module
- select it in the list and press the "Install" button at the bottom left corner of the dialog

ED: after taking a look at your screenshot:

OK, so here is your problem - that Calendar component from the tutorial is for web pages. If you are developing a Swing application, then you need it's analogue for Swing. This link might help you then: [netbeans forum](http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic7995.html)

If you are developing web application, then you are doing it wrong. Try to start with this tutorial: [webapp tutorial](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html)

That palette is context sensitive. It doesn't show components for .jsp web pages when you are editing something other than .jsp page. That is why you are not seeing that Calendar while editing .java files.

Hope that helps

Comment: Alright, I'm stuck here: http://yfrog.com/07screenshotoxhp. How do I get the component on my palette now?